# How to keep buttons from misaligning with each other when resizing the page?

Tags: css, button, grid

I have a grid container that has 2 pricing plan cards inside. Each has an img at the top followed by descriptions of the plan and finally a cta button. However, when I try to resize the page the one button moves up or down so they are not lined up. I tried to figure out a media query to maybe add padding but that only works in a small range of screen sizes before it jumps again. Any pointers to keep the buttons aligned would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [example].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.